# how to pass class type list in constructor in c#

Tags: c#

I have a class

```
 class AttendanceReport : BaseBean
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int serialNo { get; set; }
    public string aadharCard { get; set; }
    public string employeeName { get; set; }
}
```

and i have i list of that class

```
List<AttendanceReport> list=New List<AttendanceReport>();
```

i want to pass this is in a constructor of another class

```
public popUpGrid(List<AttendanceReport> arr)
```

but it show me an error in the class of the constructor that inconsistent accessibility

please help me with that error or give me another option to how i can send tabular data to another class without using DataTable or DataSet

Answer (score 2):

Your class `AttendanceReport` is not marked as `public`. This is the reason for the error you encounter.

Answer (score 0):

Change Your Class as Below

```
Public class AttendanceReport : BaseBean
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int serialNo { get; set; }
    public string aadharCard { get; set; }
    public string employeeName { get; set; }
}
```

So it is accessible to Outside `Context` i.e. in other Classes

Comment: ooh yaa i didn't get attention of it